# why does conditional list.insert() in python add additional items to list

Tags: python, list, insert

```
h = list('camelCase')

for i in range(len(h)):
    if h[i].isupper():
        h.insert(i,' ')
```

`print(h)` returns: `['c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'l', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'C', 'a', 's', 'e']`

I expected: `['c', 'a', 'm', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'C', 'a', 's', 'e']`

since there's only one uppercase letter "C"

Comment: Try putting `print(h, i, h[i])` before `if h[i].isupper():` and see what is happening. Usually it is not good to modify a list during a `for` loop over the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are iterating over the range of the list, and when you find a capital letter, you insert the space in that position, which means that the capital letter will be move to the next position, therefore once you find a capital letter it will simply add a space and check that letter again.

Your `h[i]` right now would print the following:

```py
`c`, `a`, `m`, `e`, `l`, `C`, `C`, `C`, `C`
```

My recommendation would be to not modify the original list, but do it in a separate one:

```py
h = list('camelCase')
new_text = ''

for i in range(len(h)):
    if h[i].isupper():
        new_text += ' '
    new_text += h[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the original list first.

The reason the space letters are added repeatedly is that `" "` is added in the list `h` so `"C"` is taken continuously until the index `i` reaches the original length of `h`.

```
h = list('camelCase')
a = h.copy()

for i in range(len(h)):
    if h[i].isupper():
        a.insert(i,' ')
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the list you are iterating on isn't always a good idea but if you want to apply it on the same list you can use while loop:

```
h = list('camelCase')

i = 0
while (i < len(h)):
    if h[i].isupper():
        h.insert(i,' ')
        i += 1
    i += 1
```